# itextsharp AND c# AND AddDocument when merging one of the documents is really small

Tags: c#, itext

I am merging pdf files using itextsharp and for specific files the size of the file when added is very small.  I am using .net 4.5.1 and the latest itextsharp dll.  Below is my code and pictures of what the files look like.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jim

[MergedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l2gX.jpg) [OriginalImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKji5.jpg)

```
  public static void MergePDFs(string outPutFilePath, params string[] filesPath)
        {
            //Define a new output document and its size, type
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

            PdfCopy copyProvider = new PdfCopy(document, new    System.IO.FileStream(outPutFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            document.Open();

            List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
            foreach (string filePath in filesPath)
            {

                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(filePath);

                copyProvider.AddDocument(pdfReader);

                pdfReader.Close();
            }

            document.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What is going wrong? Could you show us the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error.  For two specific pdf files one of them when imported is 1/5 the size it should be.  Tried to add the images to this post but they do not appear to be working yet.

Comment: When your input files are different sizes, your result pages will have different sizes well. You need to scale them to the same size.

Comment: I tried using getpagesizewithrotation and it did not make a difference.  Also, tried importing the files and also  the pdfsmartcopy and same result.

Comment: Please share the PDFs in question. Does one of them probably define a custom default user unit?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbmwpwpw0ukuo2g/CombineTest.zip?dl=0) Here is a link to the zipped files.

Comment: Ok, It actually is pretty simple... the page in 10.pdf is 612pt x 792pt while the page in 20.pdf is 2528pt x 3300pt. If you want them to be the same size, you will have to scale one.

Comment: How do I rescale the size of the document in c# using itextsharp.  Cannot find any examples on how to do this.  thanks in advance for any help.